# When exactly is new instance being added into ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, puppet

I have already running LBS with auto-scaling group which may spin up a new instance every time it's necessary (eg. during high load).

As of now, it spins up the new instance just based on AMI id, but as I'd like to puppetize our infrastructure. I don't want to build whole new AMI after every change. Therefore, I'd like to use AMI with just clean OS + properly configured puppet agent.

What I'm struggling to find out is **when (in which point) Amazon actually adds the new instance into the load balancer**? Obviously I don't want dead machine being added into LB.
And the machine may be considered as dead before the whole puppet config is applied, which may take some time after booting up.

Does the LB just wait until port 80 is available on that machine, or is there any command in the boot script, which ensure that all services are running and then notify AWS via some API to actually add itself into LB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options. You can set a health check on the instance via TCP port or ping a target URL. This is configured on the ELB itself under the health checks section (in the gui).

If you were to use the ping option: if your instance was available on port 80/index.html, the health check would fail until that page is up and available. Once the index.html page is available it would be listed as "In service" and then the ELB would direct traffic to it.

If you picked the TCP option: Basically as soon as the instance is up and the security group is added to it, the instance is considered "in service" by the load balancer.

You'll probably want to choose the ping option for your particular use-case

Here's some additional documentation on the subject: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/as-add-elb-healthcheck.html

Comment: Which means, that the web server must start as the last thing (all other services like memcache etc. must be already running and be properly configured).